# Unable to connect JDEEnterpriseOne Database through java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

The sample code  I have written:

```
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:oracle:enterpriseone://server1:6016/PD910;enterpriseone.role=*ALL;databaseName=server1;user=jde;password=jde123";
    String sql = "SELECT ABAN8 FROM *LIBL.F0101 F0101";
    Class.forName("com.jdedwards.jdbc.driver.JDBCDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

Its giving following exception for  : DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

Exception:

```
Mon Jun 30 07:52:17 CDT 2014: [INFO] [PERFORMANCE] com.jdedwards.jdbc.driver.JDBCDriver.connect():  13313 ms
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:enterpriseone://server1:6016/PD910;enterpriseone.role=*ALL;databaseName=server1;user=jde;password=jde123
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    at ConnectToJDEE1.main(ConnectToJDEE1.java:21)
```

Am using  e1dadriver.jar

Are there any extra setting or jar required ??

Comment: Are you sure  that the jar is in the classpath?

Comment: yes, the jar is in the class path.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, e1dadriver.jar has several dependencies.
The latest documentation shows the following additional jars:

- avalon-framework-cvs-20020806.jar
- castor.jar
- commons-codec-1.3.jar
- commons-httpclient-3.0.jar
- commons-logging.jar
- e1dadriver.jar
- fop.jar
- images.jar
- j2ee.jar
- jmxremote.jar
- jmxremote_optional.jar
- jmxri.jar
- OWResource.jar
- rtf2fo.jar
- xalan.jar
- xerces.jar
- xmlparserv2.jar

Additionally, xalan and xerces must be replaced under certain circumstances.
All of these files should be provided in the DADriver_EAR.jar file.

For more information, check the documentation at:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17984_01/doc.898/e14692/interactive_reporting.htm#BABCAJJE